JPA Native Query with Timestamp with LocalDateTime.now() to write (update) and then select the same records that were just modified
I am using Timestamp with now = LocalDateTime.now() with Native Query and update and later I am using the same now variable to select from database. MS SQL. I am using this Java Spring Boot. In a Repository. I hope this is enough explanation and code otherwise I can try do some more description. Thank you for all the info.
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "UPDATE xy SET ts = :timestamp", nativeQuery = true)
    void update(LocalDateTime timestamp);

    
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM xy WHERE  ts = :timestamp", nativeQuery = true)
    List<List<String>> select(LocalDateTime timestamp);

    // and then I call

    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    update(now);
    list = select(now);

    // and the list is empty


My guess is that there is some conversion happening, probably due to timezones. I suggest that after your Java code performs the UPDATE, that you check the actual value of column ts (in [database] table xy) to verify whether it is exactly the same as variable now in your Java code.

Actually the analog to Timestamp is not LocalDateTime but Instant. What MS SQL type do you have?

To guard against time zone problems it’s better to use timestamp with time zone (or equivalent) in the database and either OffsetDateTime or Instant in Java depending on what works. Not that a time zone problem seems very likely to me as the reason for this particular issue; but still better safe than sorry. :-)

Bear in mind that the statement that datetimeoffset adds time zone awareness is actually incorrect. A timezone is a politico-geographical construct based on a world region and not simply an offset. Having said that, it will give you the most realistic out-of-the-box approach to storing the info based on OffsetDateTime. If you want or need, you can store the actual timezone separately

Using @Modifying annotation makes the persistence context outdated, to overcome this issue you can specify a property -
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)

to make sure PC fetches the entity from database.

Thank you. I will try this at some point. I forgot how I solved the problem at the end. But I think I did some other workaround
